# Making GridView-like widget with fixed amount of children

Tags: flutter

I am super confused. I need to make carousel where in each page there is a 3x2 grid (fixed) to show cards. However after a lot of searching, I cannot seem to find any flutter widget that can make a grid with fixed amount of children. I cannot use GridView either because somehow the height of the GridView is like fixed and I need to scroll to see half part of the last row. So, is there any way I can make this grid with fixed number of children without GridView since it is scrollable? Or at least make the GridView to follow its content's height? TYIA

Comment: try this package it makes grids height as per its content , https://pub.dev/packages/intrinsic_grid_view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want your grid to be scrollable the Table widget might work for you: [Table class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Table-class.html)

Comment: thank you for the answer, it really worked, however, i would like to keep the table have 3 columns and 2 rows even if, for example, there is only 2 child in there. right now it there will only be 2 columns and the column width will split only into 2, but i want to keep it 3 columns. do you know the way to do it? i dont see it in the docs, and as far as i know there are no other similar questions in SO

Comment: @Rhendyrivaldo You can set the `defaultColumnWidth` property of the table to make columns of a specific width regardless of the number of Columns in the table. If you know the size of the Widgets that are laid out in table, then use `defaultColumnWidth: FixedColumnWidth(widthOfYourWidget)`. If you don't know the size of the Widgets, then use `defaultColumnWidth: IntrinsicWidth()`.

Comment: @Rhendyrivaldo You can also set the width of the columns individually using `columnsWidths` property of the `Table`. You can see how that's done in the code example on the page that I linked in my answer.

Comment: @Rhendyrivaldo But please also note, that the documentation says, that if you only have 1 row in your table, it is more appropriate to use the `Row` instead of the `Table`. So maybe you should do some conditional rendering, and return either a `Row` or a `Table` based on the number of widgets you want to lay out on a specific screen of your carousel. Although I don't think this is a matter of life and death, it's more like a performance improvement thing.